# Notation of Integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

When I face ordinary differential equations (ODE), I usually use integrating factors. So I try finding "well" integrating factors.

---

For example, we consider the following ODE.
$$
u'+p(x)u=q(x)
$$
Let $\mu$ or $M$ be some function, and multiply both sides:
$$
\mu u'+\mu pu=q
$$
Then we suppose this ODE can be expressed as
$(\mu u)'=q$. So
$$
\mu u'+\mu'u=q
$$
Since 2nd equation and 3rd equation are the same, the following equation must be satisfied for $\mu$.
$$
\mu'=\mu p
$$
this ODE is easier than 1st equation.

---

I wonder why integrating factors are usually expressed as $\mu$ or $M$. It is easy to understand why most mathematical notations came into use, such as integral symbol($\int$), but I cannot make a good explanation of this notation.

Comment: Perhaps inspired by "'m' like multiplicator (multiplicand?)".